# AngularJS redirect user to payment gateway after submitting form

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a angularjs project. 
I'm in the process of integrating payment gateways. I'm stuck with the gateway submission.
Basically without angularjs, when a user clicks "Pay Now", the form submits the data to the gateway along with some hidden fields and takes the user directly to the payment gateway.

Whereas in angularjs, when the user clicks "Pay now", nothing happens.

I have the form in angularjs html file as follows.

```
<form action="payumbtn.action" method="post" name="payuForm" id="payuForm" style="display: block">
        <input type="hidden" name="key" ng-model="payumbtn.merchant_key" />
        <input type="hidden" name="hash" ng-model="payumbtn.hash"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="txnid" ng-model="payumbtn.txnid" />
        <input name="amount" type="hidden" ng-model="payumbtn.totalCost" />
        <input type="hidden" name="firstname" id="firstname" ng-model="payumbtn.firstName" />
        <input type="hidden" name="email" id="email" ng-model="payumbtn.email" />
        <input type="hidden" name="phone" ng-model="payumbtn.mobile" />
        <textarea name="productinfo" ng-hide="true">{{payumbtn.productinfo}}</textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="surl" ng-model="payumbtn.success_url" />
        <input type="hidden" name="furl" ng-model="payumbtn.failure_url"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="service_provider" value="payu_paisa"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="lastname" id="lastname" ng-model="payumbtn.lastName" />
        <input type="hidden" name="udf1" id="udf1" ng-model="payumbtn.udf1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="udf2" id="udf2" ng-model="payumbtn.udf2" />
        <input type="submit" value="Pay now"/>
    </form>
```

Now the {{payumbtn.xxxx}} data is fetched from a previous post so don't bother it.

**What I need**
I need the form to submit the payment data to the gateway and redirect the user to the gateway.

Comment: do i understand correctly - you want to change the above JS code to angularjs code?

Comment: I do not know if that's what you mean. In angularjs you need to have ng-model to to pass data from input to function, like in this plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/vXz4aiq1AwHF5VmGp6ix?p=preview

Comment: I have converted the `value="` to `ng-model="`. Still the pay now button does no action. The above code is already angularjs. I want the submit button to work like a basic HTML form submit. (Submitting the form data and redirecting the user to gateway). Also I don't want to pass the model values to a function or something of JS.